# Problem with URL bar in a PWA, I see it, but other users not

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps

Second problem is with multi domain application. This is multi tenancy app which users can have premium accounts with custom domains. After redirect users to their custom panel (for users which don't see URL bar), URL bar is appeard. I think problem is with `assetlinks.json`, which is configured for only one domain generated apk application. I started search in google and I found this package (https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/tree/master/demos/twa-multi-domain), I used it, but after redirect to panel with custom domain, URL bar is appeard.

Comment: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL (custom domain) pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool?

Comment: @Mathias Yes, I think i made it working, but now problem is with adding to android application in statement_assets and <data> in <activity> tags every time new user custom domain. Is possible to make it dynamically? I know I can add wildcard, but it won't work with custom user domains, because we don't know which address user will have.